# how make this multi thread more efficient

Tags: python, multithreading

multithreading in python

2 files

messages.txt with indefinite number of lines
keys.txt with indefinite number of lines

example:

keys.txt have 4 items

messages.txt have 12 items

my program will create 1 thread for each item on keys.txt(4 threads) calling a function with 2 items from messages.txt and so on until the message.txt file ends.

example2:

keys.txt have 2 items

messages.txt have 6 items

**keys.txt**

> key1 key2

**messages.txt**

> message1 message2 message3 message4 message5 message6

create 2 threads each time

```
        |message1
THREAD1 |   --> key1
        |message2

        |message3
THREAD2 |   --> key2
        |message4

loop(60) NEED LOOP 1 MINUTE

        |message5
THREAD1 |   --> key1
        |message6
```

Comment: Use multiprocessing.

Comment: Where is `keys.txt` in your example? What makes you think it is not efficient? Why do you think it gets more efficient by using multithreading? Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hi Eckhardt, how are you? the code is an example, I currently use it but it's not very efficient, the topic is informative, I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: You can't use the above code, it's not valid Python, so you must be using something else. In particular, it doesn't explain the relation between the two files. Maybe read [mcve] as an inspiration. Also, "The algorithm should get 2 items for each line of the keys.txt file, if have 6 items on keys.txt 6 threads with 2 items in each thread, 12 items." -- can you split up this sentence? Put each statement into one sentence. As it stands, I can only guess what you mean there, but guessing is a bad idea.

Comment: totally redefine the question and approach.

Answer (score 0):

A good lead of improvement could be to avoid preload all files in memory before starting feeding worker threads.

Take a look at the concept of generators and iterators in Python. I would open both files as iterators on lines, and maybe use high-order fonctions like zip, to feed the threadpool's Map.